# Write as the internal direct product of two proper subgroups in every possible way.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-product

> Let $|a| = 4$ and $|b| = 2$. Write $\left \langle a \right \rangle \times \left \langle  b \right \rangle$ as the internal direct product of two proper subgroups in every possible way.

Let $G=\left \langle a \right \rangle \times \left \langle  b \right \rangle$, we have that $|G|=8$.
I've been looking for a way to write $G$ as the internal product of proper subgroups and so far I can think of two ways: $G=\left \langle a \right \rangle  \left \langle  b \right \rangle$, since $\left \langle a \right \rangle \times \left \langle  b \right \rangle \cong \left \langle a \right \rangle  \left \langle  b \right \rangle$ and $G=\left \langle a^3 \right \rangle  \left \langle  b \right \rangle$. Is this correct? are there more possibilities?

Comment: $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle a^3\rangle$ are the same subgroup, so that is the same decomposition. But you could take $a^2b$ and generate another subgroup of order $2$, or $ab$ to generate another subgroup of order $4$.

Comment: @ahulpke In conclusion, should I also look in the products for possible generators of $G$?

Comment: No -- you need to lok at generators for other normal subgroups.

Comment: As a further hint,  I think there are four ways of doing this.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have found these four ways: $ \left \langle a \right \rangle  \left \langle b \right \rangle,  \left \langle a \right \rangle  \left \langle a^2b \right \rangle,  \left \langle ab \right \rangle  \left \langle a^2b \right \rangle,  \left \langle  ab \right \rangle \left \langle b \right \rangle$